# styling the dropdown menu according to mysqli_fetch_array results

Tags: php, mysqli, drop-down-menu, switch-statement, text-styling

My purpose is to styling the each dropdown menu row with different background color but I do not understand why my code is not working.
I get the sub-category names from table and match these names with the texts in the switch statement.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu col-xs-12" role="menu">

                    <?php

                    $kategorisor=mysqli_query($baglanti, "SELECT * FROM kategori_alt WHERE kategori_ad = 'BILGI'");
                    $kategoricek=mysqli_num_rows($kategorisor);
                    $say=0;
                    while ($kategoricek=mysqli_fetch_assoc($kategorisor)) { $say++;


                    $colorcek="SELECT kategori_alt_isim FROM kategori_alt WHERE kategori_ad = 'BILGI'";
                    $result=mysqli_query($baglanti,$colorcek);
                    while ($bgc=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ ?>

                    <li style="background-color:<?php

                    switch ($bgc['kategori_alt_isim']) {
                        case 'Kişisel Gelişim':
                        echo "#FFCC80;";
                        break;
                        case 'Matematik':
                        echo "#FFB74D;";
                        break;
                        case 'Fen':
                        echo "#FFA726;";
                        break;
                        case 'Sosyoloji':
                        echo "#FF9800;";
                        break;
                        case 'Dil':
                        echo "#F57C00;";
                        break;
                        case 'Psikoloji':
                        echo "#EF6C00;";
                        break;
                        case 'Felsefe':
                        echo "#EF6C00;";
                        break;

                        default:
                        echo "#EF6C00;";
                        break;

                    } ?>"><a class="dropdownkategori" href="<?php echo $kategoricek['kategori_alt_link']; ?>"><?php echo $kategoricek['kategori_alt_isim']; ?></a></li>

                    <?php
                }
                }
                ?>
```

Comment: `switch ($bgc['kategori_alt_isim'])` `$bgc` is an assoc array with one item in it called `kategori_alt_isim`

Comment: And you need a `while ($bgc=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){`

Comment: Thank you. It helped to fetch these colors to sub categories but I guess two queries in a row caused a loop.
I updated the code over here.